# JAVASCRIPT: make class visible after other class has been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a simple php chatbox and am starting with the css/javascript first. What I want to do is when I click the header of the chat, the main part of the chat will slide up and show, and when I click the header again, it will go down, similar to the Facebook chat. I have tried things like

```
$(".chatheader").on("click", function () {
    $(".chatcontainer").style.display = 'visible';
}
```

but none of them work, here are my codes

HTML

```
<div id="chatbox">
        <div class="chatheader"><div class="chatheadertext">chatboxheader</div></div>
        <div class="chatcontainer">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#chatbox {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.chatcontainer {
    height: 360px;
    width: 320px;
    border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
    float: right;
    top: 100%;
    display: none;
}
.chatheader {
    font-family:'PT Sans';
    background: #00b4ff;
    width: 322px;
    height: 51px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 360;
}
.chatheadertext {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xGh0stSn1p3r/u52ym/)
I have `display: hidden;` on my .chatcontainer and I would like to use javascript to make the display visible when .chatheader is clicked. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **[.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)**:

```
$(".chatheader").on("click", function () {
    $("#chatcontainer").slideToggle();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u52ym/2/)**

---

Final code should look like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".chatheader").on("click", function () {
        $("#chatcontainer").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: It works when I test it on JsFiddle, but not when running it on my pc. Do I need to have Jquery included in my script for it to work?

Comment: Yes, you need to include jQuery as well as put your code inside DOM ready handler. Please check my updated code.

Comment: very good example.. i was not aware of slideToggle() is it latest jquery feature??? @Felix BTW +1

Comment: @EhsanSajjad No, this method is added from version `1.0` as you can see from the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery `slideDown()` method:

```
$(".chatcontainer").slideDown();
```

And use `slideUp()` to hide it later.